# Show that $I_{12}\ne-0.0189$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

For $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, let $$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{2-x} \,dx.$$ The value taken for $I_1=\ln2$ is $0.6931.$ If the recurrence relation is now used to calculate successive values of $I_n$ we find $I_{12}=-0.0189$ (you are not required to confirm the calculation). Explain carefully both why this cannot be correct and the source of the error, given that all intermediate arithmetical operations have been performed exactly.

I am not sure how to answer the question?

Comment: Hint: positive + positive + ... + positive = positive.

Comment: To have a guess at the source of the error, I think one must know the recurrence relation used.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$I_n= \int_{0}^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{2-x}dx= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\right)dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4}+..+\frac{x^n}{2^n}+...\right)dx $$

$$I_n = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x^n}{n}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}+...+ \frac{x^{2n}}{2n\cdot2^n}+...\right]^1_0$$

$$I_n= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+...+\frac{1}{2n\cdot2^n}+...\right)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer If I'm not mistaken isn't the radius of convergence of the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is $|x|<1$ and in this particular case $|x|< 2$? $0$ is contained in this interval so why can't $x=0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah I see.. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

For $x\ne2,$$$\frac{x^{n-1}}{2-x}=\frac{x^{n-1}-2x^{n-2}+2x^{n-2}}{2-x}=-2x^{n-2}+\frac{2x^{n-2}}{2-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another hint:** Substituting first $t=1-x$ followed by $u=1+t$, and then expanding the numerator via the binomial theorem, the integral becomes:

$$\begin{align}
I_{n}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{2-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)^{n-1}}{1+t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{(2-u)^{n-1}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{u}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}2^{n-1-k}(-1)^ku^{k}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}2^{n-1-k}(-1)^k\int_{1}^{2}u^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}$$